# Filtering model angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have model like this:

```
[{
  "TaskDate": "2015-01-04T00:00:00",
  "TimesheetList": [{
    "WorkItemId": 24,
    "ProjectId": 13,
    "ProjectName": "My Project",
    "UserId": 12,
    "UserName": "Some User",
    "Date": "2015-01-04T22:00:00",
    "Task": "Some text",
    "TimeWorked": 2.0,
    "Note": null
  }]
}]
```

This data views in table, and I need to add filters by user and by date(from-to)
How to do this in angular?
I add my example to [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/vKwwM11icL4lrGrCJYyK?p=preview)

Comment: What you want filters by `user and date(from-to)` OR `user or date(from-to)` ?

Comment: @shaishabroy, both variants

Comment: create angular custom filter

Comment: Check out this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515431/ng-repeat-filtering-data-by-date-range

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function in your controller example :

```
$scope.filterFN = function(model){

          //here check for the userid and date range
          //return true or false

};
```

In your html...

```
ng-repeat="model in models | filter: filterFN"
```