# How to Filter data using date in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date

I have list of student names & i want to filter names using two dates.

I have two date pickers one is for `from date` another one is for `to date` .if user select `2015-10-19` as `from date` and `2015-10-20` as `to date` , then name list should show between this two dates.

example user selected above dates

list should be

1. Ramesh
2. Vignesh
3. Sarath
4. Gomal

I have added my code below some one can help me out .

```
<!--begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!--language: lang-js -->

angular.module("date", [])
    .directive("datepicker", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            el.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                        });
        }
    };
})
.directive("datepicker1", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            el.datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                        });
        }
    };
})
    .controller("dateCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.names= [{

        id: "1",
        C_Name: "Ramesh",
        C_Phone: "*******",
        C_Option: {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-19T09:52:26.507Z"
        }
        }

    }, {
         id: "2",
        C_Name: "Suresh",
        C_Phone: "*****",
        C_Option: {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-21T09:52:26.507Z"
        }
        }

    }, {
         id: "3",
        C_Name: "Vignesh",
        C_Phone: "*******",
        C_Option: {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-20T09:52:26.507Z"
        }
         }

    },
    {
         id: "4",
         C_Name: "Sarath",
        C_Phone: "******",
        C_Option: {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-20T09:52:26.507Z"
        }
        }

    },

    {
         id: "5",
         C_Name: "Sundhar",
        C_Phone: "******",
        C_Option: {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-21T09:52:26.507Z"
        }
        }

    },

    {
         id: "6",
         C_Name: "Rajesh",
        C_Phone: "******",
        C_Option: {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-18T09:52:26.507Z"
        }
        }

    },
    {
         id: "7",
         C_Name: "Gomal",
        C_Phone: "******",
        C_Option: {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-20T09:52:26.507Z"
        }
        }

    }


    ]




});

 <!-- language: lang-html -->

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="date">
<div ng-controller="dateCtrl">
  <!-- jq -->

   <!-- ng -->
    From Date:<input type="text" datepicker ng-model="date2" />
  <span>{{date2}}</span>
   To Date:<input type="text" datepicker1 ng-model="date3" />
  <span>{{date3}}</span>
  <br><br><br>
  <label>List Of Names</label>

         <br>


        <div ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search" >
            <br>{{name.C_Name}}
            <br>



         </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

[demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aQCm/38/)

Comment: create watch on two model then filter the source by date range

Comment: you can create a custom filter for it there you can filter the data provided.

Comment: i want only 2015-10-19 detail. how can i get only 2015-10-19 detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/swhhuxx8/8/)

**Change in HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names | myfilter:date2:date3" >
```

**Change in JavaScript:** Add following custom filter

```
moduleName.filter("myfilter", function() {
  return function(items, from, to) {

    var arrayToReturn = [];        
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){   

        var test = new Date(items[i].C_Option.date.$date);
        var month = test.getMonth()+1;
        var date = test.getDate();
        var year = test.getFullYear();
        var newDate = year+"-"+month+"-"+date            
        if (newDate>= from && newDate <=  to)             {
            arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
        }
    }

        return arrayToReturn;
  };
})
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25521779/3186722

Comment: if i select same date in both date picker it should show the detail

Comment: What do you mean by detail? all elements of the array?

Comment: i want only 2015-10-19 detail. how can i get only 2015-10-19 detail

Comment: its not working .http://jsfiddle.net/swhhuxx8/6/ .check this fiddle here it should show Ramesh and Rajesh but here its showing only Ramesh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98560/discussion-between-martin-and-khalid-hussain).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nameSpace = angular.module('tst',[]);

nameSpace.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.date1 = "27-05-2010"
  $scope.date2 = "29-07-2015";
  $scope.orders = [
  {
    "date1": 1306487800,
    "date2": 1406587800
  },
  {
    "date1": 1196487800,
    "date2": 1406597800
  }]
});

// parse a date in dd-mm-yyyy format
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('-');
  // Note: months are 0-based
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]); 
}

nameSpace.filter("myfilter", function() {
  return function(items, from, to) {
        var df = parseDate(from);
        var dt = parseDate(to);
        var arrayToReturn = [];        
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            var tf = new Date(items[i].date1 * 1000),
                tt = new Date(items[i].date2 * 1000);
            if (tf > df && tt < dt)  {
                arrayToReturn.push(items[i]);
            }
        }
        
        return arrayToReturn;
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tst"> 
<div ng-controller="MyController"> 
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>From:<input  ng-model="date1"  type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
                        <td>To:<input  ng-model="date2"  type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | myfilter:date1:date2">
                    <td>{{order.date1 * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.date2 * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i want 2015-12-20 name list what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom filter function for this functionality and compare the date on the records against the start and end date entered by user.

Im using `moment.js` for date comparisions as it the best library for date comparisions.

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="name in names | filter: dateRangeFilter('C_Option', date2, date3)">
     <br>{{name.C_Name}}
     <br>
  </div>
  <span>{{resultsCount}} records returned</span>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
    $scope.dateRangeFilter = function(property, startDate, endDate) {
     return function(item) {
         $scope.resultsCount = 0;
        if (item[property] === null){
          return false;
        }
        var localEndDate ='';
        if(typeof endDate === 'undefined' ){
            localEndDate =  moment(new Date(),"DD-MM-YYYY") +'T23:59:59.000Z';
        }else{
         localEndDate = endDate + 'T23:59:59.000Z';
        }

        var currentDate = moment(item[property].date.$date, "DD-MM-YYYY");
        var s = moment(startDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");
        var e = moment(localEndDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");
        if (currentDate >= s && currentDate <= e) {
            $scope.resultsCount++;
           return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
  }
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/8aQCm/44/)

**Update : code updated to show the count of records after filter.**

Comment: if i want only one date names like 2015-12-20 what should i do

Comment: you mean when only `start date` is entered and `end date` is kept blank ?

Comment: yeah otherwise both input field if i select same date

Comment: its not working properly.i have selected  2015-12-18 as from date and  2015-12-19 as to date .its showing only Ramesh.but here it should show Rajesh and Ramesh

Comment: problem is that when you selected the `start date` or `end date` by default the time is set to start of the day were as your names  list  record has time set to `9pm` thats why its not filtering properly. anyway i have fixed it you can check the updated jsfiddle link  `http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/8aQCm/43/`

Comment: i have selected 2015-12-18 and 2015-12-19 its showing only Ramesh .here it should show Ramesh and Rajesh

Comment: i dont know which link your checking , try this http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/8aQCm/43/. its working fine for me. also when you dont give end date, filter considers today as end date

Comment: if i want particular date.what should i do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98562/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-martin).