# Compare dates inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I have:

```
vm.today = new Date();
vm.calendar = ...fairly complicated logic...
```

In my view I have:

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in vm.calendar">
    <td ng-repeat="day in week track by $index">
        <div>
            calendar date: {{ day.date }}<br>
            today: {{ vm.today }}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's what's in a sample cell:

```
calendar date: 2016-09-01T00:00:00
today: "2016-09-07T16:58:12.434Z"
```

How could I add an `ng-if` to the above that would only show if `day.date` was greater than or equal to `vm.today`

Something like this example (that doesn't work):

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in vm.calendar">
    <td ng-repeat="day in week track by $index">
        <div ng-if="day.date >= vm.today">
            calendar date: {{ day.date }}<br>
            today: {{ vm.today }}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

P.S. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412897/compare-dates-in-ng-repeat) already on SO, but it didn't seem useful for my issue.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just filter by date instead? Because that's over here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25515431/215552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this you should create a controller function that accepts two parameters and returns a boolean. Also consider that you may be comparing dates to strings, so parsing is required before you can perform a meaningful comparison. So your div tag would look something like `<div ng-if="vm.shouldDateBeShown(day.date, vm.today)">` and your function should use a library like [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) (my personal preference) to do parsing and comparing:

```
vm.shouldDateBeShown = function(dt, today){
  var datea = moment(dt);
  var dateb = moment(today);
  return datea.diff(dateb, 'days') >= 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is great. Didn't know I could pass a function to `ng-if`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create filter.

```
 <td ng-repeat="day in week track by $index | dateCompare">
```

JS :

```
  .filter('dateCompare',function(){
            var arrFinalWeek = [];
            return function(weekInChild,weekDataFromParent){

                    var timeStamp = new Date(date).getTime();
                    weekInChild.forEach(function(date,key){

                            if(new Date(date).getTime() >= timeStamp){
                                arrFinalWeek = arrFinalWeek.concat(date);
//depend on requirement u can delete it from existing  or 
//concat new array and return it
                            }
                    });

                return arrFinalWeek;
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the ng-if condition to `ng-if="day.date >= vm.today.toJSON()"`

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in vm.calendar">
    <td ng-repeat="day in week track by $index">
        <div ng-if="day.date >= vm.today.toJSON()">
            calendar date: {{ day.date }}<br>
            today: {{ vm.today }}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WUe2P/49/)