# Angular-filter based on category menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an array of arrays to display data...

```
<div class="form-container" ng-repeat="formblock in forms">
    <div class="form-block" ng-repeat="form in formblock | filter:dateFilter">
        <div class="formURL">{{ form.url }}</div>
        <div class="formCount">{{ form.count }}</div>
        <div class="formSubmit">{{ form.date }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have a menu below this with certain date values. I want to filter the data when an option on the menu is clicked...

```
<div class="date_menu" ng-repeat="singledate in dates">
    <button ng-click="dateFilter=singledate" class="option">{{singledate}}</button>
</div>
```

As you can see I tried to filter the data but it is not working as expected. In fact nothing happens when I click on a menu option.

How can I filter the data based on the menu value `singledate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using basic angular filters:
(my code below was taken and altered/augmented from their documentation)

links:

filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

previous question : [ng-repeat filtering data by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515431/ng-repeat-filtering-data-by-date-range)

I imagine that the previous question will help you go farther but hopefully my code will get you started, answer your direct question with a plnk too.

```
<body ng-app="">
  <div class="left">
    <div ng-init="sessions = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276', date:1288323623006},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY', date:1287323623006},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', date:1288323623006},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678',  date:1288323623006},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', date:1244323621006},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678',  date:1188323623006}]"></div>
    <div ng-init="dates = [1288323623006,1287323623006, 1244323621006, 1188323623006]"></div>

    <table id="masterList" >
      <tr><th colspan="3">Tutoring Sessions Available</th></tr>
      <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="session in sessions | orderBy : 'date' ">
        <td>{{session.name}}</td>
        <td>{{session.date | date: 'short'}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="search-results" >
      <tr><th colspan="3">Tutors Available At Chosen Date-Time</th></tr>
      <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="tutor in sessions | filter:tutorDate ">
        <td>{{tutor.name}}</td>
        <td>{{tutor.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{tutor.date | date: 'short'}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>
      <form>
        <label>Session Times</label>
        <div ng-repeat="aDate in dates">
          <p>
            - {{ aDate | date: 'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a'}}  
            <input type="radio" name="filterDateChosen" ng-model="$parent.tutorDate" ng-value="aDate" >
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tDCdlrEKhi9RGM07bSTa?p=preview)

Comment: This helped a lot, but could you change the `input` to a `button` tag? I tried doing it but the filter will not work. I tried `<button ng-model="$parent.dateFilter" ng-value="aDate">{{aDate}}</button>`

Comment: <button ng-click="$parent.tutorDate = aDate">
            - {{ aDate | date: 'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a'}}  
          </button>  will work.  That won't stylize the button class to show which button is selected without some more lines of code

Comment: define a class named 'highlight-class' and you can have a class applied to active button with <button ng-click="$parent.tutorDate = aDate" ng-class="{ 'highlight-class': $parent.tutorDate == aDate}"> I'm not sure that is best form to styling though.. hard to say