# How to filter records between two dates?

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-filters

I am working in AngularJS and i need to add filter according to selected date range from calendar. My dates are coming in two fields "from" and "to" and i need to show records according to expiry date which is coming in json array.

when user select the date range and click on search then i need to get selected records between that two dates.This is my js in controller file where i am getting start and end date in this format "yyyy-mm-dd".Please help.

```
 localStorageService.set('usersOpen', users.openUsers);
  localStorageService.bind($scope, 'usersOpen');

users.myUsers = myUsers;
        function myUsers(start_date,end_date){
            DataService.myOpenUsers()
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.usersOpen.length = 0;
                $scope.usersOpen.push({'data': response.data.results});
            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
```

From data service i am getting this json response.

```
{
  "results": [{
    "id": "999896",
    "description": "Description Testingggg",
    "picturesUrl": [],
    "assigID": [{
      "userId": "67767776",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "test",
      "lastName": "User",
      "pictureUrl": "",
      "notifyStatus": "None",

    }],
    "expiryDate": "2016-10-14T17:48:50.100Z",
    "createdUserId": "8887900",
    "status": "Open",
    "dtModified": "2016-10-14T12:21:27.431Z"
  },{
    "id": "999897",
    "description": "New Tested Description",
    "picturesUrl": [],
    "assignedTo": [{
      "userId": "887997",
      "email": null,
      "firstName": "testing",
      "lastName": "users2",
      "pictureUrl": null,
      "notifyStatus": "None",
      "devices": []
    }, {
      "userId": "887997",
      "email": "testing@hotmail.com",
      "firstName": "Testing",
      "lastName": "User2",
      "pictureUrl": "",
      "notifyStatus": "None",

    }],
    "expiryDate": "2016-10-11T09:46:09.100Z",
    "createdUserId": "887997",
    "status": "Open",
    "location": {
      "lat": 12.1,
      "lon": -3.1
    },
    "dtModified": "2016-10-11T09:36:30.217Z"
  }]
}
```

This is html where i am getting records.

```
<ul>                        
<li ng-repeat="users in usersOpen[0].data track by $index" class="{{users.status}} {{yit.id}}">                         
<div class="content-box">
<div class="text-box">  
{{users.description}}   
</div>
{{users.expiryDate}}    
</div>
{{users.firstName}} 
 </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: There are many ways to achieve what you want... you can try and use a custom filter like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515431/ng-repeat-filtering-data-by-date-range

Answer (score 1):

You can define a filter, using filter method:

```
angular.module('app').filter('dateBetween', function() {
     return function(data, config) {
         if(!angular.isArray(data)) return data;
         var result = [];
         var start = config.start;
         var end = config.end;
         var dateProperty = config.dateProperty;
         data.forEach(function(chunk) {
             if((chunk[dateProperty].getTime() <= end.getTime() && check.getTime() >= start.getTime())
                result.push(chunk);
         });

         return result;
     }
)
```

Say you have a model in $scope usersOpen, you can apply the filter in your html code, and the endDate, startDate are also property from the same controller (I'dont know the logic you used to retrieve dates ):

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="user in usersOpen | dateBetween : { start : startDate, end : endDate }"> {{ user.name }} ... </li>
</ul>
```

usersOpen should be an array of users so the filter I linked (which is clear I think) to apply filtering.

Comment: how i can use this in my html and where i need to define that filter will match the date with expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

```js
           var product_data = [{
             "id": "999896",
             "description": "Description Testingggg",
             "picturesUrl": [],
             "assigID": [{
               "userId": "67767776",
               "email": "test@gmail.com",
               "firstName": "test",
               "lastName": "User",
               "pictureUrl": "",
               "notifyStatus": "None",

             }],
             "expiryDate": "2016-10-14T17:48:50.100Z",
             "createdUserId": "8887900",
             "status": "Open",
             "dtModified": "2016-10-14T12:21:27.431Z"
           }, {
             "id": "999897",
             "description": "New Tested Description",
             "picturesUrl": [],
             "assignedTo": [{
               "userId": "887997",
               "email": null,
               "firstName": "testing",
               "lastName": "users2",
               "pictureUrl": null,
               "notifyStatus": "None",
               "devices": []
             }, {
               "userId": "887997",
               "email": "testing@hotmail.com",
               "firstName": "Testing",
               "lastName": "User2",
               "pictureUrl": "",
               "notifyStatus": "None",

             }],
             "expiryDate": "2016-10-11T09:46:09.100Z",
             "createdUserId": "887997",
             "status": "Open",
             "location": {
               "lat": 12.1,
               "lon": -3.1
             },
             "dtModified": "2016-10-11T09:36:30.217Z"
           }];

           var startDate = new Date("2016-10-04");
           var endDate = new Date("2016-10-14");

           var resultProductData = product_data.filter(function(a) {
             return new Date(a.expiryDate) >= startDate && new Date(a.expiryDate) <= endDate
           });
           console.log(resultProductData);
```

Comment: how i can return all records in array?