# How to filter the data by Future and Past Dates

Tags: angularjs

> HI, I am new to angular,  I want to show data by past data from
>   yesterday's date, and show data of today+future date.

```
//Here is the HTML code for Past Events
<div ng-repeat="event in events | filter:pastDate">
<p>{{event.name}}
<div>

//Here is the HTML code for Future Events
<div ng-repeat="event in events | filter:futureDate">
<p>{{event.name}}
<div>
```

> Each event has a Start Date and End Date, 
>   Can anyone please explain how to achieve this.

Comment: If greater than today then FutureDate else if smaller than today then PastDate.

Comment: @Kranthi can you give some more information about your question, like what is the structure of the event object etc.?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515431/ng-repeat-filtering-data-by-date-range

Comment: @sreeramu event_name, event_info, event_startdate,event_enddate

Comment: @Kranthi this example may help you : http://jsfiddle.net/154f9az8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var d = new Date();        
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
    $scope.events = [{date:new Date}, {date: new Date()},{date: d}];     
    prepareDate = function() {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setHours(0);
      date.setMinutes(0);
      date.setSeconds(0);
      return date;
    }  
    $scope.pastDate = function(actual){
      return actual.date < prepareDate();        
    }
    $scope.futureDate = function(actual){
      return actual.date >= prepareDate();        
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <h4>Past:</h4>
    <div ng-repeat='event in events | filter : pastDate'>{{event.date| date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</div>
    <h4>Future:</h4>
    <div ng-repeat='event in events | filter : futureDate'>{{event.date| date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</div>
</div>
</body>
```