# Filtering data from json in javascript

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

[image of the response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBnwx.png)[here is another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i7zA.png)
I was able to get the result from an API using request.

**API**

```
https://jobs.search.gov/jobs/search.json?query=nursing+jobs
```

What i want to know is how to filter data from `json` array

how would i filter it using date? for example i want to filter 
and show data which start_date is `only == today`, `start_date of this week` , **and/or** `and start_date of this month`. that the data that will show was based on the date filtered.

i want to know how to filter the data using the date in `json` like `"date:" "1/01/18"`, by just using date data from `json`.

**the controller**

```
function AppController($scope, TestFactory) {
    /* console.log("AppController is now available.");*/
   /* var testdata = {};*/
    $scope.testdata = [];
    TestFactory.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.testdata = response.data;

          console.log("Data:",$scope.testdata);
    })
the service
function TestFactory($http) {

    return {
      getData: getData
    };

    function getData() {
      return $http.get('https://jobs.search.gov/jobs/search.json?query=nursing+jobs').then(function(response) {
        return response;
      }, function(error) {
        return error;
      });
    }
  };
```

**the front**

```
<ion-slides options="options_day" slider="slider_day">
            <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="event in suncorpdata">
              <div class="now-viewport">
                <div class="event-image">
                  <!-- <img ng-src="{{ event.image }}"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="event-placeholder">
                  <div class="event-title">{{event.id}}</div>
                  <div class="event-details">
                    <div>{{ event.position_title }}</div>
                    <div>{{ event.organization_name }}</div>
                    <div>{{ event.start_date }}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ion-slide-page>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat filtering data by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515431/ng-repeat-filtering-data-by-date-range)

Comment: can you put a one record of your `json` please? your image i not complete

Comment: I have added it sir , just please view the image above