# AngularJS - Filter by date

Tags: angularjs, date

I have a list of items that came in a **result** from the **API**.
In my view, I present this **results** whit an **ng-repeat**.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"></div>
```

heres my **API** response.

```
2017-01-17T09:35:38.429Z
2017-01-03T10:00:00.000Z
2017-01-27T14:34:55.179Z
```

I need to filter by date, i.e if the items are more than 3 months old show.

Comment: `if the items are more than 3 months old show` - this is filtering, not sorting...

Comment: Thanks for the help Roee !!

Comment: Can you help me whit this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat filtering data by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515431/ng-repeat-filtering-data-by-date-range)

Comment: There are great examples in here: `https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_orderby.asp` and here `https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp`

Answer (score 0):

assuming its an array:

```
let items = ["2017-01-17T09:35:38.429Z",
"2017-01-03T10:00:00.000Z",
"2017-01-27T14:34:55.179Z"]
```

do this

```
let threeMonthsAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 7776000000)
items = items.filter(date => { threeMonthsAgo.before( (new Date(date)) ) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You display the item based on your condition, in your case should not be older than 3 months.

`<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-if="!isOlderThan3Months(item)">item</div>
</div>`

```
function isOlderThan3Months(date){
   return new Date().getTime() - new Date(date).getTime() > 1000 /*ms*/ * 60/*s*/ * 60/*min*/ * 24/*h*/ * 30/*days*/ * 3/*months*/ )
}
```

Where `condition` can call a function to calculate the difference between dates. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript) for multiple ways to do this.